# Best way to log/persist application exceptions on AWS

Tags: exception, amazon-web-services, logging

We got some web applications and webapi applications running on the AWS. Does anybody know what is the best practice of error/exception logging for AWS app?

I found cloudwatch may sounds an alternative, but i seems it focuses on measurement, and I have not found a way of how to use it.

Currently, we log to DB, but we want to find a way to visualize it in the future and make the log more standard. So that, it will be more compatible in the future.

Comment: CloudWatch has a separate feature called "CloudWatch Logs" that sounds like what you are looking for.